# Vue.js - DataTable: The data is displayed but the first row shows the message "No data available in table" after render data

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I am using data-table in Vue.js in a laravel project. the data has reloaded well in data-table. but the problem is the data retrieve after loading data-table. because, in the first row of data-table says "No data available in table"!! how do I solve this problem.???

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="data-table">
                <thead style="background:#eaeaea;">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>No of items</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Created_at</th>
                    <th><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr v-for="(categories, key) in tableData" :key="key">
                    <td>{{ categories.name_categories }}</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>
                      <label v-if="categories.status == 'y'" class="badge mr-2 pull-left badge-success">Active</label>
                      <label v-if="categories.status == 'n'" class="badge mr-2 pull-left badge-danger">Disabled</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ categories.created_at }}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#" @click="editModal(categories)" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"> <i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(categories.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"> <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>


loadCategories(){
        var app = this;
        axios.get('/api/categories',{
            params: {
              company : app.selectedOutlet
            }
        })
            .then(function (resp) {
                app.tableData = resp.data.categories
                $( () => { $('#data-table').DataTable({
                      "retrieve": true,
                      "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                      "language": {
                          "paginate": {
                              "previous": "<i class='fas fa-arrow-left'></i>",
                              "next": "<i class='fas fa-arrow-right'></i>"
                          },
                          "lengthMenu": 'Display <select class="custom-select">' +
                              '<option value="10">10</option>' +
                              '<option value="20">20</option>' +
                              '<option value="30">30</option>' +
                              '<option value="40">40</option>' +
                              '<option value="50">50</option>' +
                              '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
                              '</select>',
                          "info": "Showing page <b class='text-info'> _START_ </b> to <b class='text-info'> _END_ </b>  of <b class='text-info'> _TOTAL_ </b> entries"
                      }
                  })
                })
            })
            .catch(function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            })
      }
```

Comment: where does this `No data available in table` message come from?

Comment: When I add new data

Comment: this is screenshot before i create https://pasteboard.co/IHD8CRe.png and after https://pasteboard.co/IHD9goY.png plase help me !!

Comment: where **in the code** does this message get created - screenshots are like bums, everyone has one, doesn't mean I want to see it

Comment: first thing I will usually do when tracking down AJAX requests like this is to open dev tools in chrome and go to the network tab ... reload your page and watch the xhr requests and see exactly what the server is telling you.